# What is Eric Bana saying in Chinese in this scene?

Tags: dialogue, translation, funny-people

In [Funny People](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1201167/), Eric Bana's character can speak Chinese (Mandarin).

In [this scene](https://www.traileraddict.com/funny-people/speaks-mandarin), he says something to his children in Chinese, but I don't know what he says.

It sounds something like: " 觉得__你的再见 "; but I'm not sure.

[This source](https://www.fluther.com/63635/in-english-what-does-the-chinese-spoken-at-the-dinner-in/) and a native Mandarin speaker I asked both said his accent is too bad to interpret. One answer on the linked source says he's asking them if they want to eat brussel sprouts.

**Does anyone know what he said?**

Comment: I think he says Chi de xia ni de something. You might have better luck asking this in the chinese language exchange site

Comment: One thing for sure, there is no mention of brussels sprouts